# Dictionaries and Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I've just started my adventure with programming. I really like the subject, but sometimes I come across something that I do not completly understand.
Like this, for instance:

```
//Complete this code or write your own from scratch
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, Integer> phonebook = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            String name = in.next();
            int phone = in.nextInt();
            phonebook.put(name, phone);

        }
            // Write code here

        while(in.hasNext()){
            String s = in.next();
            int phonenumber = phonebook.get(s);
            if(phonebook.equals("null") == true){
                System.out.println("Not found");
            }
                else if(phonebook.equals("null") == false){
                    System.out.println(s + "=" + phonebook.get(s));

                }
       }
     in.close();  
    }
}
```

I should have obtained such an output but I get something like this:

Your Output (stdout)

```
sam=99912222
```

Expected Output

```
sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933
```

Comment: And which part do you not understand?

Comment: Hint: `null` and `"null"` are not the same thing

Comment: `phonebook.equals("null") == true` looks strange

Comment: What is the input? It looks like the issue comes from the fact that you are not dealing the all the three inputs but only with the first one.

Comment: you are calling equals of the map, why ?

Comment: I used equals in order to check the actual value. If there was a string (key), without an int (value), then the output would print out the "null".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phonebook` is a Hashmap. It cannot equal a String of `"null"`

```
if(phonebook.equals("null") == true)
```

I believe you are confused about how to appropriately check for `null` values.

When a key in a Hashmap does not exist, it returns `null`, not `"null"`. Also, you need to check the value, not the Hashmap itself.

Therefore

```
Integer phonenumber = phonebook.get(s);
if(phonenumber == null){
   System.out.println("Not found");
}
else {
    System.out.println(s + "=" + phonenumber);
}
```

Then, unrelated issue `if (val == true)` is just `if (val)`. And no need for an `else if` if you only invert the condition

Comment: I don't know how but the issue was

Comment: I don't know how but the issue was
        int phonenumber = phonebook.get(s);

Comment: And should have been 
        Integer phonennumber = phonebook.get(s);

Comment: Just did. It solved the problem, and i am very thankful for your support! A lot of learning ahead of me i guess.